# How to make a slash command with spaces, to "categorize" commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I make slash commands have spaces? As you can see in this image from another bot, it uses spaces to categorize commands something like `/<category> <command> <arguments (if necessary)>` , and at the same time the command can also be used without using slash like `/react angry` and just `!angry` work the same way. How can I do something like that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Ywr.png

I tried using hybrid commands, but I haven't been able to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 1):

They're so called "groups" in `discord.py`

```py
from discord.app_commands import Group

group = Group(name="category1", description="Description for category1 commands")

@group.command()
async def subcommand(interaction):
    ...


@group.command()
async def subcommand2(interaction):
    ...


tree.add_command(group)
```